# How do you integrate through a data frame indexed by date time?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, import_price that is indexed by date-time and I would like to compare each of the value in the second column with a number to generate a vector of 1 and 0 signals.

[image]

However, when I tried to use enumerate to iterate through the data frame, the head, which contains characters always gets read first, and an error message of *'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'* was given.

Due to earlier operations with the data frame, I could not just use header = 1 with the read.dsv. How do you get around this?

```
T = len(import_price) 
signal = np.zeros((T, 1)),


for time,price in enumerate(import_price):
    if price < 10:       
       signal[time] = 1
    else:
       signal[time] = 0
```

Comment: I meant "iterate" not "integrate"

Comment: Then edit your question. Please add details, presumably you'd have to skip headers "by hand".

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[df['column'] > 10, 'column'] = 1
```